Suppose $G$ acts on $Cay(G,S)$ co-compactly, can we conclude that $G$ is finitely generated?
Let $G$ be a group with $S$ being its generating set. Suppose $G$ acts on $Cay(G,S)$ co-compactly, can we conclude that $G$ is finitely generated?
I know the converse is true: if $G$ is finitely generated, then the ball $K:=\overline{B_e(1)}$ is compact, with
$$ G\cdot K=Cay(G,S)$$
Therefore, let $\varphi:Cay(G,S)\rightarrow Cay(G,S)/G$ be the quotient map, then:
$$ Cay(G,S)/G=\varphi(K)$$
is also compact.
How about the other direction? Is there any counterexample or can we prove this? Thanks!

Yes, this is true, and it's quite easy.
By the cocompactness hypothesis, the quotient graph $Cay(G,S)/G$ is a finite graph.
It follows that the action of $G$ on $Cay(G,S)$ has finitely many edge orbits.
However, by definition of the Cayley graph, the set $S$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the edge orbits of $Cay(G,S)$. The set $S$ is therefore finite.
